# How to get collision detection working?

Tags: c#, silverlight, oop, collision-detection

I have been trying for a while now and I cant seem to get my collision detection working, at the moment i have it commented out due to the fact its not working.

Here are the errors I am getting when I uncomment.

**Errors**

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OOPigEatingApple.Apple>' to 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl'

The best overloaded method match for 'OOPigEatingApple.MainPage.DetectCollision(System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl, System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl)' has some invalid arguments

The best overloaded method match for 'OOPigEatingApple.MainPage.RemoveApple(OOPigEatingApple.Apple)' has some invalid arguments
```

Problem is I can not fix these errors due to lack of understanding, any help rectifying these problem will be fantastic.

**Code**

```
namespace game
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        Pig myPig;
        List<Apple> myapples;

        private int appleTimer = 0;
        //int appleCount = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myPig = new Pig();
            myapples = new List<Apple>();

            Image myImg = new Image();
            myImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pig3.png", UriKind.Relative));
            myImg.Width = 80;
            myImg.Height = 60;
            myPig.Content = myImg;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myPig);
            Canvas.SetLeft(myPig,100);
            Canvas.SetTop(myPig, 50);

            foreach (Apple a in myapples)
            {
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(a);
            }
            CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(CompositionTarget_Rendering);
        }

        public void AddApple(Apple a)
        {
            myapples.Add(a);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(a);
        }

        public void RemoveApple(Apple a)
        {
            myapples.Remove(a);
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(a);
        }

        public void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            appleTimer += 1;
            if (appleTimer > 60)
            {
                appleTimer = 0;
                AddApple(new Apple());
            }

            for (int indx = 0; indx < myapples.Count; indx++)
            {
                myapples[indx].Update(LayoutRoot);

            }

           // if (DetectCollision(myapples, myPig))
            {
             //     RemoveApple(myapples);
            }     
        }




        private void UserControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Up)
                this.myPig.Move(Direction.Up);
            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
                this.myPig.Move(Direction.Down);
            if (e.Key == Key.Left)
                this.myPig.Move(Direction.Left);
            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
                this.myPig.Move(Direction.Right);
        }

        public bool DetectCollision(ContentControl ctrl1, ContentControl ctrl2)

        {

            Rect ctrl1Rect = new Rect(
                    new Point(Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)),
                                         Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty))),
                                 new Point((Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + ctrl1.ActualWidth),
                                         (Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + ctrl1.ActualHeight))
                         );

            Rect ctrl2Rect = new Rect(
        new Point(Convert.ToDouble(ctrl2.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)),
                                        Convert.ToDouble(ctrl2.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty))),
                                new Point((Convert.ToDouble(ctrl2.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + ctrl2.ActualWidth),
                                        (Convert.ToDouble(ctrl2.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + ctrl2.ActualHeight))
                        );

            ctrl1Rect.Intersect(ctrl2Rect);
            return !(ctrl1Rect == Rect.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        for (int indx = 0; indx < myapples.Count; indx++)
        {
            myapples[indx].Update(LayoutRoot);
            bool collided = DetectCollision(myapples[indx], myPig);
            if (collided) {
                // the apple and the pig have collided. Do something here.
            }

        }
```

Try this.

EDIT: Also, if you are going to remove the apples within the loop, make sure the decrement the indexer so you don't skip an apple:

```
            if (collided) {
                // the apple and the pig have collided. Do something here.
                RemoveApple(myapples[indx]);
                indx --;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
if (DetectCollision(myapples, myPig))
```

you are passing a list of apples as the first parameter. However, your method

```
public bool DetectCollision(ContentControl ctrl1, ContentControl ctrl2)
```

expects a content control as the first parameter. That's what the compiler means when it complains

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl'

That won't work. A content control is a user interface element, whereas a List is a data structure. They are two fundamentally different things. It *might be* that your apples derive from content controls, in which case you would still need to pass *one* apple to the method instead of *a whole list*.